# How to create an array of items from multiple nested values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop, object

The array I'm attempting to work with is in the following format (There could be more or less objects inside the array):

this.selected_sum_version can have multiple groups:

```
this.selected_sum_version.sum_item_groups = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "GROUP 1",
        "version_id": 1,
        "sum_items": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "type": "formula",
                "sum_item_group_id": 1,
                "formula": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Formula NAME",
                    "sum_item_id": 1
                },
                "summary_text_box": null,
                "grid": null,
                "chart": null
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "order": 2,
                "type": "text_box",
                "sum_item_group_id": 1,
                "formula": null,
                "text_box": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Wei",
                    "sum_item_id": 4
                },
                "grid": null,
                "chart": null
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "order": 3,
                "type": "text_box",
                "sum_item_group_id": 1,
                "formula": null,
                "text_box": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Lan",
                    "sum_item_id": 5
                },
                "grid": null,
                "chart": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "GROUP 2",
        "version_id": 1,
        "sum_items": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "order": 1,
                "type": "text_box",
                "sum_item_group_id": 4,
                "formula": null,
                "text_box": {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "JFM",
                    "sum_item_id": 7
                },
                "grid": null,
                "chart": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "GROUP 3",
        "version_id": 1,
        "order": 3,
        "sum_items": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "order": 1,
                "type": "text_box",
                "sum_item_group_id": 5,
                "formula": null,
                "text_box": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "JC",
                    "sum_item_id": 6
                },
                "grid": null,
                "chart": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Each object inside of the this.selected_sum_version.sum_item_groups array has a 'type' and there can only be 4 different things that 'type' can be: grid, chart, formula and text_box.

I need to create a new array, starting with newArray = [] of ALL the names of each object depending on the type. Using the example above, the newArray would be:

```
this.newArray = ['Formula NAME', 'Wei', 'Lan', 'JFM', 'JC'].
```

Depending on the 'type' inside of this.selected_sum_version.sum_item_groups, then one of 'formula, text_box, grid or chart' will NOT be null and will have an id, name and sum_item_id. I need newArray to be an array of all of those names.

The code I've written below works for the purpose however it's not written very efficiently. Is there a more direct and cleaner way of writing this?

```
var emptyArray = [];

this.selected_sum_version.sum_item_group.forEach(element => {
        elementtwo.sum_items.forEach(elementthree => {
            if (elementthree.type === 'formula') {
                newArray.push(elementthree.formula.name);
            } else if(elementthree.type === 'grid') {
                newArray.push(elementthree.grid.name);
            } else if(elementthree.type === 'chart') {
                newArray.push(elementthree.chart.name);
            } else if(elementthree.type === 'text_box') {
                newArray.push(elementthree.text_box.name);
            } 
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested the below code, but it looks like you can use the value inside `type` directly instead of checking the value first.

```
this.selected_sum_version.sum_item_group.forEach(element => {
        elementtwo.sum_items.forEach(elementthree => {
                newArray.push(elementthree[elementthree.type].name);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is no more efficient than your way of doing it but the code will be a bit cleaner.

```js
var emptyArray = [];
var types = new Set(['formula', 'grid', 'chart', 'text_box']);

this.selected_sum_version.sum_item_group.forEach(element => {
  elementtwo.sum_items.forEach(el => {
    if (types.has(el.type)) {
      newArray.push(el[el.type].name);
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: this answer assumes there are types that you don't want to add to the array. If you want to add the name regardless of the type, then there's no need for the set or `types.has` check.

Comment: checkout my code. I think it is efficient and very clean.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to achieve this with neat code with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) and [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
const result = sum_item_groups.map(({ sum_items }) =>
  sum_items.map(
    (obj) =>
      obj.formula?.name ??
      obj.text_box?.name ??
      obj.grid?.name ??
      obj.chart?.name
  )
);

console.log(result.flat());
```

```js
const sum_item_groups = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "GROUP 1",
    version_id: 1,
    sum_items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        type: "formula",
        sum_item_group_id: 1,
        formula: {
          id: 1,
          name: "Formula NAME",
          sum_item_id: 1,
        },
        summary_text_box: null,
        grid: null,
        chart: null,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        order: 2,
        type: "text_box",
        sum_item_group_id: 1,
        formula: null,
        text_box: {
          id: 1,
          name: "Wei",
          sum_item_id: 4,
        },
        grid: null,
        chart: null,
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        order: 3,
        type: "text_box",
        sum_item_group_id: 1,
        formula: null,
        text_box: {
          id: 2,
          name: "Lan",
          sum_item_id: 5,
        },
        grid: null,
        chart: null,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "GROUP 2",
    version_id: 1,
    sum_items: [
      {
        id: 7,
        order: 1,
        type: "text_box",
        sum_item_group_id: 4,
        formula: null,
        text_box: {
          id: 4,
          name: "JFM",
          sum_item_id: 7,
        },
        grid: null,
        chart: null,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "GROUP 3",
    version_id: 1,
    order: 3,
    sum_items: [
      {
        id: 6,
        order: 1,
        type: "text_box",
        sum_item_group_id: 5,
        formula: null,
        text_box: {
          id: 3,
          name: "JC",
          sum_item_id: 6,
        },
        grid: null,
        chart: null,
      },
    ],
  },
];

const result = sum_item_groups.map(({ sum_items }) =>
  sum_items.map(
    (obj) =>
      obj.formula?.name ??
      obj.text_box?.name ??
      obj.grid?.name ??
      obj.chart?.name
  )
);

console.log(result.flat());
```

or

```
const result = sum_item_groups.reduce((acc, { sum_items }) => {
  const values = sum_items.map((obj) => {
    return ( obj.formula?.name ?? obj.text_box?.name ?? obj.grid?.name ?? obj.chart?.name);
  });
  return [...acc, ...values];
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```js
const sum_item_groups = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "GROUP 1",
    version_id: 1,
    sum_items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        type: "formula",
        sum_item_group_id: 1,
        formula: {
          id: 1,
          name: "Formula NAME",
          sum_item_id: 1,
        },
        summary_text_box: null,
        grid: null,
        chart: null,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        order: 2,
        type: "text_box",
        sum_item_group_id: 1,
        formula: null,
        text_box: {
          id: 1,
          name: "Wei",
          sum_item_id: 4,
        },
        grid: null,
        chart: null,
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        order: 3,
        type: "text_box",
        sum_item_group_id: 1,
        formula: null,
        text_box: {
          id: 2,
          name: "Lan",
          sum_item_id: 5,
        },
        grid: null,
        chart: null,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "GROUP 2",
    version_id: 1,
    sum_items: [
      {
        id: 7,
        order: 1,
        type: "text_box",
        sum_item_group_id: 4,
        formula: null,
        text_box: {
          id: 4,
          name: "JFM",
          sum_item_id: 7,
        },
        grid: null,
        chart: null,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "GROUP 3",
    version_id: 1,
    order: 3,
    sum_items: [
      {
        id: 6,
        order: 1,
        type: "text_box",
        sum_item_group_id: 5,
        formula: null,
        text_box: {
          id: 3,
          name: "JC",
          sum_item_id: 6,
        },
        grid: null,
        chart: null,
      },
    ],
  },
];

const result = sum_item_groups.reduce((acc, { sum_items }) => {
  const values = sum_items.map((obj) => {
    return ( obj.formula?.name ?? obj.text_box?.name ?? obj.grid?.name ?? obj.chart?.name);
  });
  return [...acc, ...values];
}, []);

console.log(result);
```